# Excel changes my settings for column width and row height

Tags: microsoft-excel

- I select the entire Column
- right click and select "Column width"
- enter 2.54mm
- hit enter

When I check the column width, it is 2.38mm.

Similar issue with row height.  I try to set it to 2.49mm; Excel keeps defaulting to 2.38mm.

Comment: What procedure are you using?

Comment: I select the entire Column > right click and select "Column width" > enter 2.54mm > enter.  When I check the column width, it is 2.38mm.

Comment: Which version of Excel?  The errors are extremely small.  I'm wondering if it relates to the fact that the settings need to be converted to pixels for display.  It may need to round to the closest pixel (both differences are sub-pixel distances).

Comment: As a test, when it is at the 2.38mm dimension, try tiny, successively larger values until it changes to a new value, and see what that value is.  On a typical monitor, the pixels are roughly 0.26mm apart. If the values it uses are at an increment of about that amount, it would support this explanation (the value will be different if you have a retina display or a monitor with extremely high resolution).

Comment: Please check if its you opened excel in read-only mode?

Answer (score 1):

Select the entire Column/Row, Right click on the Column/Row and select Column Width(For Column) or Row Height(For Row) and enter the desired value..
Hope this helps...

Comment: that's the process I follow; however, if you enter 2.54mm, the column width defaults to 2.38mm.  If I set row height to 2.49mm, it defaults to 2.38mm